# Angular - ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement AngularJs in my E-Commerce application. I want to know which version should I use and embed in my project. Below is one error I got when I tried to implement `ng-click`.

Did anybody face the same issue?

```
var eventModule = angular.module("eventModule", []);

eventModule.controller("eventController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.update = function () {
        alert('Update called');
    }
});
```

Html is:

```
<html ng-app="eventModule">
   <div class="row ng-scope" ng-controller="eventController">
      <input type="button" value="Update Data" ng-click="update()">
   </div>
</html>
```

It's throwing a strange error:

[image]

Comment: its working to me :)

Comment: Works for me too: http://jsfiddle.net/fhLfyqk0/
You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: thanks both for your time, that was minor mistake :)

Comment: off topic. why not use `<button></button>` instead of `<input type="button" />`

Comment: @RandomUser that doesnt really matter here I think!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change order of js references

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Previously it was on reverse order.

Comment: Actually the original order would be correct, but your version of jQuery is too old for Angular.

Comment: Should I change my jquery version, would that affect my current functionlity?

Comment: There have been major changes in version 1.9,  but using 1.7 or 1.8 could work for your application.